# Kotlin: Call a fragments function from the host activity without companion object

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have a fragment with function `getResult(): Boolean {..}` which looks through various parts of the fragment and returns the success status. I thought I could use a companion object for this but it has to access views from outside the companion so that doesn't seem to be an option.

I have also tried to return an instance (`instance = this`) via the companion object and then set that to a val, but this was also a dead end.

Extra points if there's a dynamic solution that can work with any fragment based on a passed variable, if I guarantee the fragment will always have the getResult() function

Comment: You can get existing fragments by using the `supportFragmentManager` of the Activity and using one of the `find...` functions.

Comment: Okay I have got further going down this route. Any ideas on making it more dynamic? I'm thinking I need a custom class between Fragment and each custom fragment

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're doing, but it sounds like something that an interface is better suited for than a shared superclass. As a general OOP principle, deeper class hierarchies should be avoided when possible since they make the code base less flexible and maintainable.

Comment: That's interesting because I already use an interface to send data from the fragment to the activity. but nothing I've read about them indicated they would be what I needed. I'll have another read.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to use an interface. Most straight forward and probably the most viable solution as well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33016349)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).